# Where can I find computer readable RGB values for brand name paints?

Tags: paint

Where can I find computer readable RGB values, or equivalents, for brand name paints such as Benjamin Moore, Sherwin Williams, and Behr paints?

[Edit] My interest was not so much about the specific color model of RGB, I basically needed some kind of quantitative description of available paint colors of big name brands. If RGB is not scientifically appropriate, whatever quantitative description is OK.

Comment: Under what kind of lighting?  Even if you find two paints from different brands with the exact same RGB under one kind of light, they could be different from each other under another kind of light.  This is because there's a whole spectrum to consider, and RGB is just a perspective.

Comment: I ran across http://www.perbang.dk/rgb some time ago; it might be useful.

Comment: We'd need more info to really be able to understand the intent of the question. What do you mean 'quantifiable description'? Are you just looking for a count?

Comment: Locking since this is asking for an external resource that would be off topic for the site today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your looking for the RGB equivalent of a paint swatch, your probably better off looking at Pantone colors.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantone

You can buy Pantone swatches (I think their pretty expensive though) and then use Photoshop or something to find the equivalent RGB value.

If you go into Photoshop and click on the Color Picker in the toolbar, theres a Color Libraries button that'll show you a great many Pantone colors. Click the one that matches the printed swatch and when you go back to the color picker, you'll see the RGB value.

As wikipedia says, Pantone is pretty much an industry standard, used in painting, printing, etc...

I'm sure you can in turn give a Sherwin Williams or whoever and Pantone color code and have them mix paint for you (if thats what you want).

If you want to take photos of the room you want to paint, photoshop it with the color you want from a swatch, some of the websites (we used sherwin williams) have tools to do that also, but won't produce Pantone or RGB values :(

-Mario

Answer (score 7):

You can't.  RGB is sufficient to describe the colors to be put out by a monitor, but it is not sufficient to describe the reflectivity of a surface.

Comment: Monitors are additive (rgb), Pigments are subtractive (CMYK, Spot)

Answer (score 3):

Found this site while looking for the RGB values of an Olympic paint. Regardless of all the free guesses given above, for Sherwin Williams you can find the RGB values easily. Here are most if not all of them. [https://www.sherwin-williams.com/wcm/idc/groups/public/@swpublic/@sherwin-williams/@content/documents/webcontent/mdaw/mdaz/~edisp/sw-pdf-sherwin-williams-color.pdf](https://www.sherwin-williams.com/wcm/idc/groups/public/@swpublic/@sherwin-williams/@content/documents/webcontent/mdaw/mdaz/%7Eedisp/sw-pdf-sherwin-williams-color.pdf)
I know it was an old question, hope this helps the next person wandering by.

Answer (score 0):

> I basically needed some kind of quantitative description of available paint colors of big name brands

Well, we need more info. Are you asking for the 'number of colors offered'? If so, then just call them up.

As for RGB values, RGB is a way to measure projected light--NOT reflected light. RGB is for screens (which create colors via mixing Red, Green and Blue projected light).

Paint is reflected colors. And is much different color space. The range of projected RGB colors overlaps the range of reflective colors, but they don't exactly match. In other words, there are colors that can be rendered via RGB that can't via paint and vice versa.

Pantone, as mentioned, is a good way to 'match' colors with a very particular description, but note that Pantone is typically a print color standard...for printing inks on paper. And their numbers pertain to mixing pantone brand pigments--which a paint company may or may not be using.

You can certainly take a pantone swatch to a paint store, and they can optically match it, of course.

Comment: Then i can relax my request to "CMYK values of brand name paints".  Where to get a list of such values?

Comment: Well, again, paints don't use CMYK either. You can try matching CMYK colors to commercial paint colors, but just like RGB, there will be overlap, but you won't be able to reproduce all paint colors as CMYK colors. It'd be great to understand your end goal a bit better. It might help us formulate the answer for you.

Comment: End goal is to have list of computer readable color values of all paints.

Comment: What do you mean 'computer readable'? For what purpose? Are you trying to display paint colors on a screen?

Comment: At least for displaying colors on screen.

Comment: I see. Well, one thought is to contact the paint manufacturers directly. Most of them have web sites and/or apps and such so they may very well have already attempted at finding the closest RGB value to match their particular paint colors. Do note, however, that they can never truly match--not only because of projected vs. reflected light physics, but also the simple fact that no two monitors have the same color and contrast settings.

Comment: Actually...the answer from Anon may be exactly what you need. Looks like a web site that has already compiled this information.

Answer (score 0):

Paint colors. You can indeed check the reflective value of a paint--the higher the Light Reflectance Value (LRV%) the lighter the paint, thus it reflects greater light value. RGB colors for many commercial brands and their named paints may be identified at www.encycolorpedia.com Very helpful in judging color from a computer screen. You'll also find the hex color code, and paint undertones--undertone knowledge is crucial. Staff at paint counters will not be able to ID if the paint has green, or pink undertones, for example--these undertones are difficult to work with. They mix formula RGB, CYK percentages. Note the Benjamin Moore stores may have a staff Colorist to help further--BM paints are excellent interior paint--easy application, steadfast colors, easy to spot clean.